# Why unidirectional many-to-one association in hibernate is optional

Tags: java, hibernate

The [hibernate document](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/associations.html#assoc-unidirectional-join-m21) says the `A unidirectional many-to-one association on a join table is common when the association is optional.`.

Please let me know why it is called as `optional` here?

```
<class name="Person">
    <id name="id" column="personId">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <join table="PersonAddress" 
        optional="true">
        <key column="personId" unique="true"/>
        <many-to-one name="address"
            column="addressId" 
            not-null="true"/>
    </join>
</class>
```

Comment: This might be helpful :https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=981119

Answer (score 0):

Well it is also because you either annotate or define the mapping on the entity which is the joining side already.

Also, the reason it is optional is because the @JoinColumn is done on the default column which is calculated by the concatenating the name in the owner side + _ + the name of the primary key column

so basically, if you do not specify the @JoinColumn annotation with the column name it will try to join with **address** the name in your hibernate relation in the @ManyToOne side + **_** + **id**(because this is the primary key of your Person table. 
so the default join would happen on address_id.

if you change your primary key to be personId, then the join would be on **address_personId**

Hope i was able to explain it correctly

Comment: Thanks for responding. I am not clear on the explanation given. In my example the entity that is joining side is Perosn, is that correct? I am not clear on how the `JoinColumn` annotation is used, I referred the document - http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html/ch08.html#assoc-unidirectional-join-m21, but it is not mentioned there about this annotation. And finally why is the association is called optional?

Comment: Yes, the Person entity has an Address Foreign key so that is the joining side. Basically, a JoinColumn annotation or an xml config will eventually do the same thing. The annotation is just another way to do it instead of the xml definition. When a JoinColumn is specified, you mention the join condition,  which is join by this so and so column. Why it is optional is because if you do not specify the join column hibernate knows based on the JPA annotations (ManyToOne) on how to join to the table. Which is how i had specified earlier.

Comment: This is also a good link to read up more on it http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/